# Log process output

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, process

I used the method `system` to start a process. the pid of that process is being stored in a file `worker.pid`

however I need to generate the log of this process, how can I store the output of this process?

the process is being created with this command:

```
system "bundle exec rake resque:work >> ./resque.log QUEUE=* PIDFILE=#{pid_file} &"
```

P.S.: I am using ruby 1.8, BACKGROUND=yes won`t work.
P.S.2: platform linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you're looking for is [IO.popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-popen)

This lets you fork off a subprocess and access it's output via an IO object

```
# fork off a one-off task
# and return the output as a string
ls = IO.popen("ls")
ls.read

# or return an array of lines
IO.popen("ls").readlines

# or create a continuing task
tail = IO.popen("tail -f /some/log/file.log")
loop do
  puts tail.gets
end
```

I suggest you read the documentation,
but you can also write to the stream, and do all sorts of clever stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to achieve correctly, you are looking for the Open3 class. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html

Comment: i was hoping for something more like the ">>" parameter, like: `./something >> output.txt` i now i can do that with C code, ``<< example.in >> example.out`` i was looking for something like that